# How do I isolate $i$ from this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is from economics, the teacher just leap from one equation to the other but Id would like to know the steps.

The first equation is:   $Y=a(A-bi)$
and he turns it into :   $i=\left(\frac{1}{b}\right)A-\left(\frac{1}{ab}\right)Y$

How is this happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect your $I$ is in fact a $1$.

Comment: Try not to swear in your posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$Y = a(A-bi)$

divide by $a$

$\frac Y a = A-bi$

subtract $A$

$\frac Y a -A = -bi$

divide by $-b$

$-\frac{Y}{ab} + \frac{A}{b} = i$

Comment: oh man..of course, feelling dumb now. thanks!

Comment: Happens to all of us=)

Answer (score 0):

Here it is $$\frac Ya=A-b\mathrm i\iff b\mathrm i=A-\frac Ya,\enspace \text{whence}\dots$$